# Execute function on webpage?

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon

Say a webpage has a function like:

```
function abc (){
return 'abc';
}
```

How would I execute and receive the return value of that function from my extension? I've tried this, no dice:

```
var s = getBrowser.contentWindow.abc();
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I execute a page-defined JavaScript function from a Firefox extension?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/151555/how-do-i-execute-a-page-defined-javascript-function-from-a-firefox-extension)

Comment: The answer to that question (the one that was at Google Groups) doesn't work for me.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think I've solved my own problem with:

```
getBrowser().contentWindow.wrappedJSObject.funcFromPage();
```

Comment: or `content.wrappedJSObject.funcFromPage()`

Answer (score 0):

I think that if you want to do this without major security holes, you need to be using XPCSafeJSObjectWrapper, but I'm having trouble finding good documentation on it.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XPConnect_wrappers has a little bit.  (It might be that it happens automatically when doing the above, but I'm not sure.)