# Firefox extension: invoking function from webpage js

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I'm trying to automate some boring, duplicated data entry into a web application at work.
I'm sorry if the answer is well known but I've spent hours in google trying to figure it out.
The problem is, in the web-based application none of the links are simple HTML, 'a href' type links, they use javascript.

I can see in one of the .js files for the website that the function invoked when a link is clicked is defined as follows

```
function sendEvent(eventtype, targetid, value)
```

...and with the Firefox debugger I can see that in order to do the simple page navigation I want to do, my extension has to invoke the websites js function as follows (the 'value' parm can be null)

```
 sendEvent("click", "mx709")
```

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3326348/execute-function-on-webpage) similar question. The suggested method is

```
content.wrappedJSObject.funcFromPage()
```

or

```
getBrowser().contentWindow.wrappedJSObject.funcFromPage();
```

... but running either of those lines in my extension doesn't seem to invoke the function and hence "click" the link I want clicked

EDIT 1  - in case it wasn't clear, the code I actually put into my extension was:

```
content.wrappedJSObject.sendEvent("click", "mx709[R:3]");
```

EDIT 2 - Also tried this, no dice. I have the Firefox debugger open, and a breakpoint on the top of the 'sendEvent()' function. Every time I click a link in this web app, I hit the breakpoint, when I try lines like the above (or the following), the breakpoint is not tripped

```
window.content.document.defaultView.wrappedJSObject.sendEvent("click", "mx709[R:3]");
```

Answer (score 0):

The `wrappedJSObject` method should work.

Open up scratchpad and copy paste this:

```
var indexOfTabWithMyDocument = 1; //1 means 2nd tab, 0 is first tab
Services.wm.getMostRecentWindow('navigator:browser').gBrowser.tabContainer.childNodes[indexOfTabWithMyDocument].contentWindow.wrappedJSObejct.FUNCTIONTORUN()
```

Set the environment of scratchpad to browser. And run. It will work.