# Executing injected Javascript code in a page when developing a Firefox extension

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon

I'm developing a Firefox extension which places a button in the status bar. When the button is clicked, the extension injects some Javascript  into the current page. This Javascript  has a function that I would like to invoke with some parameters. I've managed injecting the code, I've inspected the page through Firebug and verified that the JS has been injected. How can I call a Javascript function in the page from my extension?

--More information

Here's the code that I'm using to inject my Javascript:

```
var doc = window.content.document;

//Add the script
var visibilityJS = doc.createElement("script");
visibilityJS.setAttribute("type", "text/javascript");
visibilityJS.setAttribute("charset", "UTF-8");
visibilityJS.setAttribute("src", "chrome://visibility/content/scripts/visibility.js");
head.appendChild(visibilityJS);

//Call the function
alert("Executing testfunction");
window.content.document.defaultView.testFunction();
```

..and the code inside my JS file that i'm going to inject. i.e. visibility.js

```
window.testFunction = function() {
    alert("Message");
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This worked. I don't know the technicalities. I got part of the solution from Felix and part of it from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151555/how-do-i-execute-a-page-defined-javascript-function-from-a-firefox-extension/2525816#2525816).

```
window.content.document.defaultView.wrappedJSObject.testFunction();
```

Answer (score 2):

If you declare a global variable in your injected code (or explicitly set a property of the `window` object), then one way do get a reference to this element from your extension, is via the [`gBrowser`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Code_snippets/Tabbed_browser) object:

```
gBrowser.contentDocument.defaultView.yourObject
          ^-- HTML document  ^
              object         |-- window object
```

Be careful though, when you use `window` and `document` inside your code. Depending on the context it might refer to the Firefox window or the website window object.

Comment: Hi Felix. I couldn't quite figure out what you meant. I tried reading the documentation too i.e. the page that you pointed out, but i still couldn't quite get it. I tried `window.content.document.<function name>` but that didn't work. Would you happen to have a simple example or something? Thanks.

Comment: @Mridang Agarwalla: You are close. `window.content.document` should give you the same as `gBrowser.contentDocument`. But this gives you the `document` object of the website. Global variables are always properties of the `window` object of the website. `document.defaultView` should give you that object. Try `window.content.document.defaultView.<function name>`.

Comment: Hi again Felix. I still can't seem to access it. I get the following error — `window.content.document.defaultView.testFunction` is not a function. I tried invoking `testFunction` from the JavaScript console and it worked but the extension is still unable to access it. Do I add something or modify my injected Javascript code in any way? Thanks again.

Comment: @Mridang Agarwalla: If you define the function with `function testFunction(){}` then it won't work. But if you define it with `window.testFunction = function() {}` then it should...

Comment: Hi Felix. I've modified the function as you instructed. I'm able to invoke it through the Javascript console but I still get the same error as earlier when my extension tries to invoke it. I've edited my original question be more clear in how I'm going about this. Something amiss?