# Page JavaScript calling a Firefox extensions JavaScript

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon

My Firefox extension has a button which when clicked, injects some JavaScript code into the current page. How can this injected JavaScript code in a web-page call a JavaScript function in my extension? It would be helpful if someone could point me to an example.

Thanks.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4215507/executing-injected-javascript-code-in-a-page-when-developing-a-firefox-extension ?

Comment: That's his own question + the accepted answer is his own?

Comment: I did post a question a day or two back but if you read through it, you'll see that it was about invoking a script function from the extension and this is the other way around.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It boils down to dispatching events from the document object and listening for them from your extension.  You must create a listener for these events on a per-tab basis.  You may also be able to catch them using jQuery embedded in your extension.

The simplest way to do this is outlined here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Code_snippets/Interaction_between_privileged_and_non-privileged_pages

You can set up a JS library (on your page) and a matching library in your extension that allows you to do exactly this in a repeatable way.