# How to execute javascript code in the namespace (scope) of the webpage, from a firefox extension?

Tags: javascript, firefox, namespaces, scope, firefox-addon

I'm looking for a clean way to call/execute/redefine javascript code from a webpage, within firefox, through a firefox extension. My temporary solution is to use the scratchpad (Shift-F4, Ctrl-A, Ctrl-V, Ctrl-R), it works fine but is a sad work-around. Greasemonkey would be my last resort, very very last.

Here' the code so far:

**main.js:**

```
exports.main = function() {
  var data = require("self").data;
  var pageMod = require("page-mod");
  pageMod.PageMod({
    include: "*.google.com",
    contentScriptFile: data.url("my-script.js")
  });
};
```

**my-script.js**

```
$('#mydiv').html('yo')
alreadyHere.sayHello=function (){alert('Bonjour');}
```

This code halts on line #1 of my-script.js saying that $ is not defined.
Problem of namespace/scope.

How can I work within the namespace/scope of the webpage, from my extension, like I do with the scratchpad?

**Edit:** There should be a link between *window.content* of the firefox main window and *alreadyHere.sayHello* from the webpage, no?

```
window.content.(things).alreadyHere.sayHello();
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HELL YEAH.

```
window.content.document.defaultView.wrappedJSObject.$('#mydiv').html('yo')
window.content.document.defaultView.wrappedJSObject.alreadyHere.sayHello();
```

Thanks Mridang Agarwalla [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4215507/executing-injected-javascript-code-in-a-page-when-developing-a-firefox-extension?answertab=votes#tab-top)

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried in Firebug console?

And also,

Make sure you code is within

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  //your code here
});
```

and most important jQuery is properly loaded

Comment: jQuery is properly loaded on the webpage. The javascript of my extension doesn't see it. That's my problem.
Also I don't understand why you suggest me to use the Firebug console.