# Invoking functions in Page context using Firefox Add-on SDK

Tags: javascript, function, firefox-addon, invoke, firefox-addon-sdk

I am new to Firefox extension development (trying to develop an extension that controls youtube player). I am using SDK and using [pageMod](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/modules/sdk/page-mod.html) I am able to access inject my scripts and access the DOM. But I am not able to invoke any of the functions inside that page (including the flash player's function). How can I allow my *contentScriptFile* to invoke arbitrary functions in a particular page?

**Note:** I am genuinely not concerned about security yet and I've already seen few answers on Stackoverflow (including [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151555/how-do-i-execute-a-page-defined-javascript-function-from-a-firefox-extension)) but they will exposing my JS files or injecting script tags. Is there a cleaner way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

The SDK allows a back-door into the page by adding a variable called 'unsafeWindow' to the content script's scope. unsafeWindow is a direct reference to the documents window object, and as you can tell by the name it is inherently *unsafe*. The main issue to be aware of is that you should *never* trust data returned from unsafeWindow.

Comment: I've tried doing unsafeWindow approach I am still not able to invoke any of exposed methods from youtube player. Is there some other way to interact with exposed APIs of Flash player?